# Tengo un problema en Xampp al acceder a mi registro de mi gestor documental

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xampp

Me sale un error en la consola de Chrome que pone lo siguiente:
login.js:15     POST http://localhost/gestion_php/principal/validar 404 (Not Found)

mi archivo login.js tiene esto al principio:

```
const frm = document.querySelector('#formulario');
const correo = document.querySelector('#correo');
const clave = document.querySelector('#clave');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (correo.value == '' || clave.value == ''){

        } else {
            const data = new FormData(frm);
            const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url = base_url + 'principal/validar';  //base_url no tiene el error
            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.send(data);
```

Me esta diciendo que la linea de http.send(data); es la que tiene el problema.
Creo que el problema esta relacionado con mis configuraciones del Apache de Xampp pero no se que que parte.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, ¿será que es `validar.php`?